# UITextField list? How to achieve similar UI?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I came across this UI in the Geico app.  How is this "grouped" UITextField style achieved (Street, City, State)?  Is it just done by explicitly restyling 3 UITextField elements or is there a control I am missing to handle this?

[image]

Note:  I am using MonoTouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its done using the UITableView element.

Comment: Moments after posting this, the idea of UITextFields inside a UITableView occurred to me. Thanks. I think you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily enough do something like this by putting the text fields inside a UIView and setting `view.clipsToBounds` to YES, `view.layer.borderColor` to an appropriate grey, `view.layer.borderWidth` to an appropriate width, and `view.layer.cornerRadius` to an appropriate radius. Don't forget to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to be able to access the layer's properties.